# Does Google App Script PropertiesService support serialized data or arrays?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to pass serialized data, or an array, through `PropertiesService`, in order to build a dynamic table in Docs. I'm thinking of something like:

```
var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var orderList = properties.getProperty("orders");

// iterate through orderList to add rows to a table with columns like description, amount and price.
```

Is this possible, or should I fall back to work with indexes and string-manipulation for key names like:

```
var rowCount = properties.getProperty("row_count")

// for-loop till rowCount
var itemDesc = property.getProperty("item_" + i + "_description")
var itemPrice = property.getProperty("item_" + i + "_price")
```

Answer (score 1):

Both methods would work. However there are some quotas that may limit either approach.

If you were to serialize your array and save it to an orders property you would have to make sure it stays under the 9kb limit per value.

If you were to make a property for each line item you would need to stay under the 500k read/writes per day.  This number is going to be changing in the near to a flexible quota system.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#flexible_quotas_early_access

Comment: Does this have the same limit as GAS where you are not able to pass Date Items, but must first convert them to a string?

Comment: Yes the property value must be a value that can stringify or has a toString.

Comment: When you say serialize your array, you mean I encode the whole thing into 1 JSON string, then pass it to Properties as a single value? `properties.setProperty('orders', '{"order"...')`;  or do you mean you can pass an actual array?

Comment: By serialize I mean JSON.stringify your data before setting it to the  value if your property.